# How to make time return morning or afternoon

Tags: ruby, time

I've been attempting to output either `Morning` or `Afternoon` depending on the time of the day. I turned the time into a string, and tried to compare against it. Here's what I have:

```
t = Time.now
# => 2016-05-11 07:18:10 -0500
if t.to_s >= '12:00'
  'Good afternoon'
else
  'Good morning'
end
# => "Good afternoon"
```

It defaults to `"Good afternoon"`. Why is this? Is it because Ruby sets up time in a 24 hour clock? Or is it something within the coding?

Comment: Why are you comparing them as strings?

Comment: @sawa Whatever I did worked, so why not go with it?

Comment: And with the words "Whatever I did worked, so why not go with it?" we all started our journey to oblivion.

Comment: @ReggieB If it works, it works, so what's wrong with accepting it until it's finished, and making it better when it's finally done..?

Comment: With leading zeros, the lexicographical order corresponds to the chronological order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any string manipulation:

```
t = Time.now
# => 2016-05-11 20:26:11 +0800
t.hour
# => 20
```

Just compare its [`hour`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-hour) (an integer) with `12`.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing strings - which won't give you the results you expect.

`Time.now.to_s` outputs a string like: "2016-05-11 13:27:43 +0100". When you compare it to "12:00" that is a comparison of the letters in the string, and not the time they represent.

Try this instead:

```
t = Time.now

if t.strftime('%P') == 'pm'
  'Good afternoon'
else
  'Good morning'
end
```

Documentation for strftime: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'

t = Time.new
puts "Good %s" % [(t.to_i/43199).even? ? "morning" : "afternoon"]
Good morning

t += 43199
puts "Good %s" % [(t.to_i/43199).even? ? "morning" : "afternoon"]
Good afternoon
```

Note: `43199 = 12*60*60/2 - 1`

Just sayin'.